# Integrate a select pull-down in a text field in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

What I would like to do is have pull-down country select in a mobile phone number field, like the picture below, using a bootstrap [dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#buttons-with-dropdowns).

[image]

I have a mobile number form element like so:

```php
$form['mobile'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#title' => $this->t('Mobile phonenumber'),
  '#description' => $this->t('Will be used for account verification'),
  '#default_value' => $this->account->get('mobile')->value,
  '#placeholder' => '+31612345678',
  '#pattern' => ESCROW_DEFAULT_MOBILE_REGEX,
];
```

Add a separate country select dropdown is obviously possible but I would like to integrate it into the mobile number input field.

I could use JS to change the markup but I dislike the pop-in of a JavaScript solution.

I found this [link](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom), but I was wondering if there is a without having to create a custom field class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's similar [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/international_phone). It allows to choose country and enter phone number. Maybe you will find it useful.